# exporting the DHCP and DNS configuration of a Windows2022 server

Tags: windows, dhcp, dns-zone

Is there a way of exporting the complete DHCP and DNS configuration of a Windows2022 server, such that it can be migrated painlessly and installed 1:1 onto another server? I mean, not only Zones, A-records etc., but also forwarders, root hints, the whole big enchilada.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move my Windows DNS from one server to another?](https://serverfault.com/questions/76643/how-can-i-move-my-windows-dns-from-one-server-to-another) remind that the movement is the same like having a copy to a second server and using this as secondary

Comment: thank you for addressing my question, but that answer is not quite what I was looking for. In my case, the Windows Server is stand-alone and is not integrated in Active Directory. I was wondering where the configuration of both the DHCP and DNS servers is stored. Hopefully a bunch of *.conf files, or of registry entries, which can easily be exported and deployed somewhere else. :)

Comment: Have you looked into `Export-DhcpServer` and `Import-DhcpServer` PowerShell cmdlets?

Comment: look at the configuration tab, there are directories that you may need to move. it is the similar task even if its a standalone device

Comment: I would recommend to split this into two questions. Export/Import DHCP is easy with CMDlets, but DNS (when you don't want to migrate just zones) is another story.